# Restart a for loop within a for loop

Tags: python

I have two for loops.

I want to iterate through the first for loop from top to bottom.

I have a second for loop, within the first the for loop, that I want to restart each time it gets hit.

Within the second for loop, I have a break statement when I find what I need.

However, my problem is, in the second for loop, everytime I break out, the next time it gets accessed, it always starts from the next position after the previous break.

The second for loop never starts from the beginning of itself. Only from when I previously utilized break, it starts from there.

Comment: Why would you describe the code instead of posting it?

Comment: Post code. We are not mind-reading wizards here.

Comment: Lagrange took enormous pride in the fact that his treatise did not have any illustrations in it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph-Louis_Lagrange#M.C3.A9canique_analytique

Comment: It sounds like you just didn't create the second loop the correct way. but we would need to see your code to be of any help

Comment: Also, stop hitting your for loops and they'll respond better.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I really really want to type D E D but I must to resist the urge.. ugh this is hard

Comment: My internet and elektricity went out unfortunately so I am posting from my.phone.. im using openpyxl, the second for loop is for row2 in sheetOrig.ITER_rows(theRange)

Comment: @king. Please don't do that. You won't be able to use an answer until the electricty comes back, so wait until you can meaningfully edit the question.

Comment: Both for loops look like basically above, trying to go through 2 sheets and compare values, but the second fir loop doesn't start from the top of the range, only from where it last was

Comment: I'm not sure if you can simply restart python's for loop. If you want to control the iteration, maybe you should use while.

Comment: My laptop is running on battery power I can use an answer lol

Comment: I see.. yeah I tried break but it doesn't reset it hmmm

Comment: stackoverflow will probably still be here after you recharge.

Comment: You could've written something from memory, or even a small example to help... Because as far as I can tell, what you're trying to do *works*. I tested on my phone (btw, Pythonista) with nested `for` loops and a `break` statement in the second one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Python generally doesn't use pre and post incrementation and without seeing the code, I would recommend incrementing the index variable forcefully after your break statement in order to determine your values and what to do next.

```
count = 1
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(0, i):
        print(count, end='')
        count += 1
        print()
        input()
```

So change:

```
count = count + 1
```

to

```
count =+ 1
```

to see if that gives you information about your index variable in order to edit when you want to do something the break point.

Comment: The tag is Python though

Comment: Ok, changed from PHP to Python.